# Django or DjangoREST for a server of a pure group chat android app

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am setting up a server for my android chat app. It is a pure group chat i.e. each message will be sent to multiple users and not just a single user

Since I have a background in Python, I would prefer to pick a python based web framework.

So as I was searching, I came across "Django" and "DjangoREST". After reading a lot about them, it seems that DRF (Django Rest Framework) is a RESTful implementation of Django and will let you make applications that are light and scalable.

Since this is for the first time that I am setting up a web service, I can not relate or understand this completely. Also, I feel that what I want to accomplish, could be accomplished on either of the 2 platforms.

Therefore, it will be great if some one could share some very basic and key differences(if any) between the 2 frameworks. So that I can decide which on to pick up.

Comment: do you want to deal with A) JSON/XML or B) HTML forms/POST data? A = REST, B = Native Django. Simplfied but...

Comment: The device will send and retrieve  JSON objects to and from the server. The app logic will then parse the objects and feed the relevant information to the app's layout components.

Answer (score 1):

There are no differences. `Django` is a web framework and `Django Rest Framework` makes it easier to create REST services in `Django` itself.

It doesn't replace `Django`. It adds to it.

Comment: @Smaxter Have you tried open source projects? Why to start new ones? http://kandanapp.com/

Comment: I did have followed some open source projects and also the official tutorials. Since I have just entered into web hosting, I have to study a lot of topics which takes some time. Also I want to make one application end to end myself, so that I can get feel of the things and become more confident about what I am doing.